# Indexable type with overloaded functions

Tags: typescript, overloading

I have defined an interface for the event handlers of a react component:

```js
interface IDictEventHandlers {
  [index: string]: (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>) => void;
}
```

This works fine to create objects like:

```js
const handleFoo = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {
  console.log("foo");
}

const handleBar = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {
  console.log("bar");
}

const myEventHandlers: IDictEventHandler = {
  foo: handleFoo,
  bar: handleBar,
}

<...html which sends events/>
```

But as it turns out, some of my event handlers actually need a string instead of the ChangeEvent to function. However, when I try

```js
interface IDictEventHandlers {
  [index: string]: (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement> | string) => void;
}

const handleFoo = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {
  console.log("foo");
}

const handleBar = (e: string) => {
  console.log(e);
}

const myEventHandlers: IDictEventHandler = {
  foo: handleFoo,
  bar: handleBar,
}

<...html which sends events/>
```

I get a compile error:

```
Type '(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>) => void' is not assignable to type '(e: string | ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'e' and 'e' are incompatible.
    Type 'string | ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>' is not assignable to type 'ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>'.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>'.
```

So the question, is it possible to work with indexable types which at the same time support overloaded functions?

Comment: Where is the overloaded function in this question?  TypeScript uses the term ["overload"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) in a particular way; is that what's happening here?

Comment: I'm inclined to suggest that the property type of your interface be `((e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>) => void) | ((e: string) => void);`, a union of function types.  If that works, great: let me know and I'll write up an answer.  If not, please edit the question code to constitute a [mcve] that shows why a union doesn't work for you.  Good luck!